# Quickblox Webrtc Audio Calling Swift - Documentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, quickblox

I am trying to integrate Quickblox into my existing app,
As per the documentation , I have followed all the process and the integration is done and it is working well with the text chat,

When it comes to integration of Audio and video calling functionality of the SDK I'm facing problems, In sample they have added the libraries directly or manually, In my project I have added the same libraries through the POD.

Due to their lack of documentation, I am not able to understand where to use the functions which they have provided in their existing documentation for swift like :

```
// 2123, 2123, 3122 - opponent's
let opponentsIDs = [3245, 2123, 3122]
let newSession = 
QBRTCClient.instance().createNewSessionWithOpponents(opponentsIDs, 
withConferenceType: QBRTCConferenceType.Video)
// userInfo - the custom user information dictionary for the call. 
//May be nil.
let userInfo :[String:String] = ["key":"value"]
newSession.startCall(userInfo)
```

This is the code for creating the session and calling the user, but I'm facing the difficulty on where to add this code so that it works for my app.

Below is the sample which they have provided

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat-webrtc

Thanks in advance.